# Where was Danzo when Pain attacked?

Tags: naruto

When Naruto arrived, he and the toads fought Pain. The only other people of the Hidden Leaf, in my opinion, who were powerful enough to help would be:

- Kakashi and other dead people

  Guy—not in the village

  Tsunade—in a comma

  The Uchihas—seemingly defected from the Leaf

  Danzo

Where was Danzo? He would not have wanted the Leaf to be destroyed, so I would imagine he would help here and also when Orochimaru attacked the Leaf in part 1.

Is there any hard evidence to support why Danzo didn't help in either attack?

Comment: Some of my theories: 1. He may have wanted Tsunade/the 3rd to die, so that he could be Hokage, and he would have helped after that. 2. He wasn't in the village 3. The author did not think of it

Comment: Tsunade was not in coma when pain attacked. She went into coma after the attack of Pain, and she used up a lot of her chakra trying to save the inhabitants of Konoha.

No Uchiha was left in Konoha when Pain attacked. The only two living Uchiha's were Sasuke and Itachi who had defected from Konoha and were missing nins.

Comment: he is just like vulture/hyena.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Danzo was in Konoha at the time of Pain's attack, at the Root organization's HQ. He even plays a role in the plot.

He first tells Koharu Utatane and Homura Mitokado that Tsunade was risking the loss of Fourth Hokage's legacy by recalling Naruto from Myobokuzan to the village. (Occurs in anime only.) He then kills the messenger frog Kosuke, left behind by Fukasaku to prevent the news of Pain's attack from reaching Naruto, so that the Kyuubi doesn't fall in Akatsuki's hands.

He doesn't help the village for political reasons. He knows that using Katsuyu's healing, Tsunade would prevent a total destruction of the village. He could then lie low until Tsunade is removed from power, and then become the Hokage himself. (see images below, taken from Chapter 421 and 424.)

His not helping during Orochimaru's invasion was also presumably for the same reason, that is, to try to remove Hiruzen from power and become Hokage himself. Either that, or Kishimoto had not planned for Danzo at the time.

[image: Danzo kills Kosuke]
[image: Danzo wants to end Tsunade's rule]
[image: Danzo wants to take over power]

Comment: It's the exact same with the Kyuubi's invasion. He was hoping that the Third and Fourth would fail to protect the city, so that he could rise to power. What a jerk.